# jQuery slider doesn't show if called in a div using Ajax ( creating a xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange etc.)

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I am working on a college project in Ajax and JSP, I am using some jQuery snippets available on the internet (galleria, dropdown menus etc.), I am quite confident in JavaScript, but my knowledge of jQuery is extremely limited.

In my index page, I call the main content into a div using Ajax methods ( not the jQuery Ajax, but the complete JavaScript, with onreadystatechange() and responsetext).
I also have a jQuery image slider and jQuery menu in this content. these don't work after Ajax callback. I have read about this problem that I need to re-bind events after callback but I don't understand how to.

Comment: Trust me, you're way better off being good in javascript and a beginner in jquery than the other way around. You'll make your life a lot easier though if you take a few minutes to study jquery's $.ajax method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

To re-bind events after callback

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', //default here is 'GET'
  url: '/path/to/my/file.jsp
  data: myDataVariable // Alternatively you can use data: { $("jQuerySelector").val)(); }
  success: function(data){
    if(data){
      $("body").on("bind", "elementIDorClass", function(){
        //these functions are bound on callback. do stuff   
      });
      $("someElement").html(data); //place all data returned inside of a containaer named 'someElement'
    }
  } 
});
```

Pretty straight forward. If our ajax request is successful, we return the data wrapped in a JSON object. We test to ensure the data we received is not empty, then we bind our functions to the element 'elementIDorClass'. Then, we load our data into 'someElement'.